# Charge transfer from electrode to water

Tags: electricity

This is something that's bugging me for a while.  Water is conductive because it has ions in it, which move to form a current.

But how is the charge transferred from a electrode into the water, and vice versa? Ions can be oxidized and reduced, but both require a certain potential, and we can pass current even below that potential. So how is the circuit completed?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, water conducts electricity mostly due to various salts dissolved in it. Distilled water has a pretty high resistance.

In any case, a simplified conduction mechanism in water is as follows. A voltage is applied to two submerged electrodes. The electrical field between the electrodes makes ions (salt ions or, in case of distilled water, $H^+$ and $OH^-$) move: positive ions move toward the negative electrode, while negative ions move toward the positive electrode.

As the ions arrive to the respective electrodes, they receive or give up electrons, supplied and removed by the battery, while undergoing redox reactions.

In case of a distilled water, we've got electrolysis of water, which converts water to oxygen and hydrogen gases. The details of the reactions involved could be found in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water) Widipedia article.

In summary, the circuit is powered by a battery or a power supply. The current in the water is conducted by ions, which undergo redox reactions at the electrodes. The circuit is completed by electrons carrying the current in the external wires.

Comment: "As the ions arrive to the respective electrodes, they receive or give up electrons" this part. How? Does Na+ become Na? Does Cl- become Cl2? Don't both of them require a certain amount of potential? What IS the redox reaction that is happening?

Comment: @AnniZhang You can find the details of chemical reactions associated with NaCl solution by searching for "electrolysis of brine". [Here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/17Electrochemical_Cells/17.02%3A_Electrolysis_of_Brine) is a link to one of the sources.